# Instant app upload failed - both http and https as schemes should be

Tags: android, android-intent, android-instant-apps

When I try to upload my .aab for instant app I get following error:
[image: Google Play error]

**Upload failed**
You should use both http and https as schemes for your web intent-filters.

I tried multiple versions of declaring my SplashActivity with web intent-filters but non of them get accepted by Google Play. This is my final AndroidManifest.xml that I read from my .aab.

```xml
<activity
            android:name="com.xxx.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="default-url"
                android:value="https://test.static.freeworld.cloud/start" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/scheme" />
                <data android:host="@string/app_local_host" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/start" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/station" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="test.static.freeworld.cloud" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/start" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Any help on this ?

Comment: `<data android:scheme="@string/scheme" />` What's string/scheme?

Comment: it's different URI I will use for app navigation. It's like like myapp://go.app/start

Comment: Can you try re-uploading without that intent-filter? or try combining it with the other intent-filter with http/https schemes.

Comment: I completely removed it and still I ge the same error :(

Comment: If you're still encountering this issue, then you should file to Google's Instant Apps component @ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787, make sure you provide your the affected AAB file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will solve your issue, but i encountered issues with uploading our instant app (.aab) as well. In our case we received errors that you are not allowed to use custom scheme intent-filters in your instant enabled modules.

You can try bundletool (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool) to verify your .aab package is correctly converted to .apk files.

Alternatively, you can also use the instant apps validation tool (Located at `~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/instantapps/ia` on osx) to verify your instant app.